# ¿XML con la siguiente sintaxis?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml

Estoy trabajando en visual studio c# .net framework 4.0, quiero generar un XML de esta manera (`<ext:dato>lapiz<ext:dato>`) pero no encuentro una manera de hacerlo correctamente, este es mi código;

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

doc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);

XmlElement element1 = doc.CreateElement("ext", "cuerpo", string.Empty);
element1.SetAttribute("type","ds","modeloAAA");
doc.AppendChild(element1);

XmlElement element2 = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "nivel1", string.Empty);
element1.AppendChild(element2);

XmlElement element3 = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "nivel2", string.Empty);
XmlText text1 = doc.CreateTextNode("texto");
element3.AppendChild(text1);
element2.AppendChild(element3);

XmlElement element4 = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "nivel3", string.Empty);
XmlText text2 = doc.CreateTextNode("más texto");
element4.AppendChild(text2);
element2.AppendChild(element4);

doc.Save(@"C:\Users\Carol\AppData\Local\Temp\xml_ejemplo.xml");
```

lo que he logrado es esto guiandome de unos ejemplos encontrado en la web

```
<cuerpo>
  <nivel1>
    <nivel2>texto</nivel2>
    <nivel3>más texto</nivel3>
  </nivel1>
</cuerpo>
```

pero necesito algo como

```
<ext:cuerpo>
  <ext:nivel1 valu="cfs">
    <nivel2>texto</nivel2>
    <nivel3>más texto</nivel3>
  </ext:nivel1>
</ext:cuerpo>
```

Comment: Hola, ese dato que quieres colocar lo estás sacando del archivo xsd? te lo pregunto porque por lo general eso no va en el archivo xml final

Comment: Si esta saliendo de un XSD, pero quiero hacer uno desde 0 mi principal problema es el que presente en el post ? si hay alguna manera cual seria gracias....